# Getting A private package cannot be published, when trying to publish flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to publish a flutter plugin by running `flutter pub publish --dry-run` I'm getting the following.

> A private package cannot be published.
>
> You can enable this by changing the "publish_to" field in your pubspec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turns out that I was running this command inside the example directory.

Just needed to change to the root directory of the plugin and it works fine.